# apache beam python and airflow reading from GCS results in TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument \'response_encoding\'"

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, apache-beam, google-cloud-composer

accessing a GCS bucket from Google Cloud Composer results in a type error:

```
DEBUG:apache_beam.io.filesystem:Listing files in 'gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.2019-01-20'
DEBUG:apache_beam.io.filesystem:translate_pattern: 'gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.2019-01-20*' -> 'gs\\:\\/\\/BUCKET_NAME\\/FILENAME\\.2019\\-01\\-20[^/\\\\]*'
DEBUG:root:Connecting using Google Application Default Credentials.
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 524, in __init__
INFO - skip_header_lines=skip_header_lines)
INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/textio.py", line 119, in __init__
INFO - validate=validate)
INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 121, in __init__
INFO - self._validate()
INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/options/value_provider.py", line 137, in _f
INFO - return fnc(self, *args, **kwargs)
INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py", line 178, in _validate
INFO - match_result = FileSystems.match([pattern], limits=[1])[0]
INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystems.py", line 187, in match
INFO - return filesystem.match(patterns, limits)
INFO - File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystem.py", line 705, in match
raise BeamIOError("Match operation failed", exceptions)
apache_beam.io.filesystem.BeamIOError: Match operation failed with exceptions {'gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME.2019-01-20*': BeamIOError('List operation failed with exceptions {\'gs://BUCKET_NAME/FILENAME..2019-01-20\': TypeError("__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument \'response_encoding\'",)}',)}
Command exited with return code 1
```

The bucket is located in a different gcp project and composer is running using a standard service account with right as compute-engine editor, which also has "storage object viewer" rights in the bucket.
I do not have any idea, how this error can be fixed, or if it even is an access right problem. Maybe someone can help out or point me into the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: How do you run it, provide code or command you used

Comment: I found the reason, this is caused by beam 2.9.0, in 2.8.0 it is running.

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by adding the correct package to requirements. From Apache Beam version 2.9.0 you need to have apache-beam[gcp] instead of only apache-beam to use Google Cloud Storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue with Google Cloud Composer then go to Cloud Composer Environment. And follow the below steps

Step1: Open respective Cloud Composer Environment.

Step2: Click on your respective Composer Name.

Step3: Go to "PYPI PACKAGES" tab and click on "EDIT" button.

Step4: In "Package name" side type "apache-beam" and In "Extras and version" type "[gcp]==2.9.0"

Step5: Click on "SAVE" button.

After this, it will take some time to update your composer configuration. 
When Composer is ready you can restart your dataflow task.

For more details, please refer below screenshot,
[image]